# Convergence of infinitesimal probability repeated

Tags: probability, limits, analysis

Let $p \equiv 1 - \epsilon$. Is it true that $\forall \ 1 > \epsilon > 0, \ \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \ p^n = 0$?

I just want to ask this: if the probability for an event to occur is extremely small (infinitesimal), can we still say that it would eventually occur with infinitely many repetitions?

And before that, can we show $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \ (0.9)^n = 0$ for example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If $0<r<1$ and $\eta >0$ the $r^{n} <\eta$ whenever $n >\frac {log\eta} {\log r}$ so $r^{n} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<a<1$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a^n=0$. To see this, observe that $1/a>1$
so $1/a=1+c$ with $c>0$. Then $1/a^n=(1+c)^n\ge 1+nc$ via binomial expansion. Then
$$0<a^n\le\frac1{1+nc}<\frac1{nc}$$
and as $1/(nc)\to0$ then also $a^n\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since for $0 < p < 1,$ the sequence $1, p, p^2, p^3$ is decreasing and $\geq 0,$ it has a limit.  Let's call it $L.$

Then $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} p^n = p\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}p^{n-1} = pL \\ \implies \\ (1-p)L = 0 \implies L = 0 \text{ since } 1-p \neq 0$$